# Logarithmic Spacing

Tags: audio, sampling, speech-processing

[image]What is the meaning of sampling logarithmically? How do you space the samples logarithmically? Or to rephrase the second question, *How to sample an audio signal logarithmically?* It would be appreciated if someone could explain that mathematically.

Comment: "In a few articles" <-- please cite these. I think you might be taking things out of context.

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's note $x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$ two successive samples. In the usual case of uniform sampling, the spacing between two successive samples is independent of $k$ and is given by $T$, the sampling period.
This is illustrated in the figure below.

[image]

In the case of logarithmic sampling, the spacing increases exponentially with $k$. This is again illustrated in the figure below.

[image]

Logarithmic sampling makes sense in the case mentioned in the article you cite:

> In many scientific problems it is necessary to compute the Fourier
>   transform (FT) of a function or measured response that rises quickly
>   then decays slowly with increasing abscissa (independent parameter)
>   value (an 'inverse ramp'). In such cases, it is desirable to derive
>   the function, or sample the response, with a small abscissa interval
>   during the rise, but then increase the interval with increasing
>   abscissa value.

In case you want to experiment with this, this is exactly the purpose of the Matlab function `logspace` or the equivalent `numpy.logspace` in Python.

Comment: Furthermore, this is a sepcial case of non-uniform signal sampling and to be an exact representation of the continuous signal $x(t)$, the local sampling **density** should be in accordance with the local bandwidth of the signal variations. The term slowly varying is used to indicate this aspect of the signal under concern.

Comment: The matlab function 'logspace' generates points that are logarithmically spaced. How does one sample a given signal logarithmically?

Comment: In Matlab/Python, to sample a function `f` : `f(logspace(a, b, n))`. In real life, to sample a physical signal you measure, I suppose using a classical ADC with a clock that has logarithmically spaced rising edge could work. Another way could be to sample uniformly the signal first and then "logaritmically downsample" it. (that's only hypotheses, I don't know how it is done in practice)